# integration of language translation in custom widget

Tags: qt4, qt-designer

i have developed custom widget and added into qtcreator. custom widget i have developed as text. i want to have option to display text in different language based on requirement. how can i achieve this. i found many tutorials on language translation in normal application but i want to achieve same in custom widget. how can i do that. can any one suggest me how to proceed with this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internationalization mechanism is the same for all texts with Qt. Use the tr() function and add the files with the translations (.ts files).

The following page will explain to you all you need to know to achieve internationalizationhttp://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/internationalization.html
You can then dynamically translate your visible text using the change event.

Comment: in normal application will use this "app.installTranslator(&translator);" for translation,but where as in custom widget instead of executable we wil get .so file and hence "app.installTranslator(&translator);" this line can not be included in main.cpp file

Comment: I assume when you speak about custom widget you might want to speak about plug-in for QtDesigner. So this discussion may help you: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/631-Plugin-and-internationalization

Comment: yes i meant the same thing. plug-in for QtDesigner. thanks for your help. i will go through the link.